# Kotlin generic issue, should be subtype of Nothing

Tags: kotlin, spring-test, kotlin-generics, spring-kotlin

I'm writing a simple Spring test on Kotlin and have a compilation error with generics that I can't understand. The function is below:

```
@Test
fun actuatorRootReturnsOnlyAllowed() {
    val expectBody:WebTestClient.BodySpec<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>, *> = client!!.get().uri("/app")
            .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
            .exchange()
            .expectStatus().isOk
            .expectBody(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>>() {})

    expectBody.consumeWith<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>> { result->
        val actuatorLinks = result.responseBody!!["_links"]
        Assert.assertTrue(actuatorLinks!!.containsKey("self"))
        Assert.assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("health"))
        Assert.assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("info"))
        Assert.assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("loggers"))
        Assert.assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("loggers-name"))
    }
}
```

The problem is in line `expectBody.consumeWith`. For some reason Kotlin expects type `Nothing` with the compilation error: `Error:(53, 32) Kotlin: Type argument is not within its bounds: should be subtype of 'Nothing!'`.
Actual type of `consumeWith` method is `EntityExchangeResult<T>`, however method still expects `Nothing`. I would expect something like `expectBody.consumeWithEntityExchangeResult<<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>>>` or `expectBody.consumeWith<Map<String, Map<String, Any>>>` instead.

However with type `Nothing` I get the `NullPointerException`:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.ActuatorEndpointsTest.actuatorRootReturnsOnlyAllowed(ActuatorEndpointsTest.kt:52)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestExecutionCallbacks.java:73)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestExecutionCallbacks.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
```

Below is the same working equivalent in Java:

```
  @Test
  public void actuatorRootReturnsOnlyAllowed() {
    client.get().uri("/app")
        .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus().isOk()
        .expectBody(new ParameterizedTypeReference<Map<String, Map<String, Object>>>(){})
        .consumeWith(result -> {
          final Map<String, Object> actuatorLinks = result.getResponseBody().get("_links");
          assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("self"));
          assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("health"));
          assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("info"));
          assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("loggers"));
          assertTrue(actuatorLinks.containsKey("loggers-name"));
        });
  }
```

Can anyone explain the reason why Kotlin expects `Nothing` and how this code can be corrected?

Comment: I'm not sure, but this looks like a problem (a bug?) with self-referencing Type arguments. (`<T extends S>` where `S` is a `BodySpec<B, S>` itself.
Java's generics are more forgiving than Kotlin's... Maybe file a bug or ask again in the official kotlin slack #spring channel

Comment: @Lovis thanks, I will post to kotlin slack channel if there will be no other answers.